# Word break isn't working even with width defined

Tags: html, css

I'm working on Bootstrap 4 and trying to make a horizontal slider. When I hover, a text appears with a white background with some opacity.

The issue is that the text inside is way too large even if the

tag is shorter than the container.

I know that to use word-break CSS property you need to define the `width` for example, I did try `width : 200px` but it doesn't work.

I also tried `hyphens` CSS property, `word-wrap` CSS property, `word-break` CSS property, `max-width` CSS property, `overflow-wrap` CSS property but nothing seems to work.

Do you know what I did wrong?

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Slider (Equipe)
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.employes {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
          transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  .employes > .row {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; }
    .employes > .row > .employes_container {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
              transform: rotateX(180deg); }
      .employes > .row > .employes_container .img-content {
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
        tranform: skew(-20deg); }
        .employes > .row > .employes_container .img-content:hover {
          cursor: pointer; }
          .employes > .row > .employes_container .img-content:hover .content {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            opacity: 1; }
        .employes > .row > .employes_container .img-content .content {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
          transition: all .5 ease-in-out;
          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; }
          .employes > .row > .employes_container .img-content .content .description {
            -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
            -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
            -o-transform: skew(20deg);
            tranform: skew(20deg); }
    .employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 12px; }
    .employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 10px; }
    .employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
    .employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4); }
    .employes > .row::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
      width: 350px; }
  .employes .caption-link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; }
    .employes .caption-link > div {
      padding: 10px 25px;
      background-color: #1C3B65; }
      .employes .caption-link > div p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #FFF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid employes">
    <div class="row text-center flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 employes_container mx-5 p-0">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description" style="
">
          <p>Avocat au barreau de Paris depuis 1993</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 p-0 mx-5 employes_container">
       <!-- <div class="img-content py-5" style="background:url('') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"> -->
       <div class="img-content" style="background:url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="content px-3 py-5">
         <div class="description">
                   </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: _“Do you know what I did wrong ?”_ - for starters: Code relevant to your problem/question belongs directly _into_ your question, not just dumped on an external site. [mcve] Apart from that, looking at your fiddle, I am not even sure what exactly is supposed to be the problem now.

Comment: I'm sure this is caused by the `transform: skew(x);`. Better place the `<p>`-Tag in another `<div>`, which is floating over the images.

Comment: @CBroe My work is already minimal, I only updated the slider part which was bugging, complete, I didn't upload my PHP loop for that reason and verifiable, it's working on jsfiddle..... The problem is that the <p> content isn't going in line when it's too big.

Comment: @rojadesign It's not working, I've tried already but the issue is that I'm using ACF WYSIWYG and it creates <p> tag automatically...

Comment: Your fiddle might disappear for whatever reason at any point, which would make this question worthless for future readers. Therefor, please include relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs what do you mean ? It isn't possible to break the text so it go in line ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `word-break` forces the text to break, so it can fit in the defined `width`. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @rojadesign https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break <- depends on the options .

Comment: @KévinHuang No I misunderstood the question at first but have you checked hte mdn docs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Yeah I already checked the doc, I did a width:200px;word-break:break-all; and width:200px;word-break:break-word; but it didn't work :/

Comment: FYI: if you remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `.employes > .row` then it's working. Alternatively, you can set it to `white-space: normal`.

Comment: @rojadesign Thanks ! Would you mind putting your answer so I can put it as resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`white-space: nowrap;`

to

`white-space: normal;` in `.employes > .row`.

Alternatively, remove it at all.

For more Information, visit [MDN - White-space - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).